# Как вызвать команду из модуля в discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Всем привет. Есть вопрос. Как вызвать команду в дискорд. Если я решил создать своего бота таким образом. А именно разбить его функциональность по модулям. Каждый модуль представляет собой класс со своей функциональностью. Вот пример: Главный исполняющий модуль - main.py

```
import discord
from Config.config import TOKEN
from Functionality.manage import Manager


class Components(Manager):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))


bot = Components(command_prefix='/')

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Модуль команд. Сейчас не важно какой. Важно, что отсюда должны вызываться команды: Manager.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Manager(commands.Bot):
    
    def send_hello(self):
        @self.command(name="send_hello")
        async def send_hello(ctx):
           print("hello")
```

Main - запускает бота. Из manage.py прописаны команды, которые будут что-то там выполнять.

При вызове команды send_hello. Дискорд не находит такую команду. Почему я хочу разделить по файлам разную функциональность. Потому что у бота которого, я хочу сделать будут разные функции в разных областях. И разделения всех функции по файлам я считаю самым оптимальным решением.

Ошибка, которая возникает:

```
Ignoring exception in command None:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "send_hello" is not found
```

Comment: То что внутри метода send_hello еще асинхронная функция send_hello - это так и должно быть?

Comment: Insolor, да. Эту штуку я взял из другого решеного вопроса. По словам автора она по идее должна работать.

Comment: А, вижу зачем так сделано, чтобы от self можно было вызвать декоратор command

Comment: Да. иначе не получиться.

Comment: Получится, если убрать наследование.

Comment: А как? То есть в класс manager не наследовать компоненты класса commands.Bot?А как я тогда смогу реализовать свою идею добавление функционала через классы?

Comment: Например, не пытаться все подряд запихнуть в классы. Пусть будут отдельные функции.

Comment: То есть в каждом модуле реализовать свои функции. А затем в main вызывать функции этих модулей? 
Сейчас попробовал сделать второй модуль и наследовать в components. Да, второй класс не виден. Получается что моя идея не особо рабочая.